# How to test two paired probability distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, biostatistics, paired-data

I have 50 paired samples, each sample contains the proportion of animals per length category, collected from the same source using either method A (50 samples) or method B (50 samples). Now I would like to test whether these length distributions are the same by using both methods.

Because these are the paired samples, I could imagine to compute a length distribution differences per paired sample and then compare it to a distribution with zero probability at each length bin, using chi squared goodness of fit test. However, in this case, the denominator of the Pearson’s chi-square statistic is 0 at all length bins, leading the test statistic to infinity. I can also apply the Kolmogorov–Smirnov test (if I consider the length bins as continuous), but I do not think it can handle paired samples.

1) Can someone suggest a valid statistical test of the distributions on the paired samples?

2) Are these statistical methods powerful enough to handle small sample size, such as 40, or less? Or are they sensitive to the assumptions (if any)?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38617-two-dimensional--2d--paired-kolmogorov-smirnov-test